# Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE error running Spark pipeline on hadoop cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

My java-spark code is written in Spark3.2.4 and JDK1.8, while the runtime is 2.11.12 and JDK8. I am bundling all necessary jars (uber-jar) along before triggering a spark-submit. My maven has a separate `hive-serde:3.1.4` dependency (to resolve another error).

My pipeline involves reading certain inputs from hive tables, process and dumping output back into hive.

This error gets thrown on cloud. Is this some sort of a clash of jars?

```
23/10/04 09:20:11 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySerDeParameters.extractColumnInfo(LazySerDeParameters.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySerDeParameters.<init>(LazySerDeParameters.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.initialize(LazySimpleSerDe.java:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.addColumnMetadataToConf(HiveTableScanExec.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.hadoopConf$lzycompute(HiveTableScanExec.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.hadoopConf(HiveTableScanExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.hadoopReader$lzycompute(HiveTableScanExec.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.hadoopReader(HiveTableScanExec.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(HiveTableScanExec.scala:211)
```